# Canvas dentro de forEach

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Necesito dibujar un canvas por cada elemento de la matriz, pero no me dibuja nada con el foreach , pero si saco el foreach y la function per y solo dejo el dibujo de #nodes si funciona , pero claramente solo me dibuja 1 vez

```js
 b = [1,2,3,4,5];
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
      
     function per() {
      console.log("per()");
       $('#nodes').css({
                'border-radius': '5px',
                'padding': '0',
                'margin': '0',
                'width': '200px',
                'height': '200px',
                'position': 'absolute',
                'right': '15px',
                'bottom': '15px'
     
            });
      
     }
    
     $('body').append('<canvas id="minimap"></canvas><canvas id="nodes"></canvas>');
    
            $('#minimap').css({
                'background': 'rgba(1,1,1,0.7',
                'border-radius': '0px',
                'border': '1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
                'padding': '0',
                'margin': '0',
                'width': '200px',
                'height': '200px',
                'position': 'absolute',
                'right': '15px',
                'bottom': '15px'
            });
        b.forEach(per);
            
      
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Nuevo problema: la respuesta de asier me sirve, el problema es que luego tengo una funcion fuera de todo este código que hace un document.getElementById , intenté haciendo document.getElementById($canvas); pero no me funcionó , que debo hacer?**

function per() {
for (var i = 0; b[i]; i++) {
var $canvas = $("").css({
// bla bla
}

}

Comment: Si tienes una pregunta nueva (relacionada aunque relamente no la misma), deberías crear una pregunta nueva en lugar de editar la que ya tienes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas en tu código.

La función `per` no crea ningún objeto, simplemente cambia el estilo del objeto `nodes` existente.

Tanto el canvas minimap como el nodes lo estás creando en la sentencia `$('body').append`

Después la función per sí se ejecuta 5 veces pero lo único que hace es cambiar 5 veces el estilo del canvas per (que como no tiene color de fondo no se llega a ver).

La función per debería crear el objeto canvas y añadirlo al DOM.

Mira el siguiente ejemplo. En la función per creo un nuevo objeto canvas y lo añado al body. Le he puesto color de fondo azul para que se vean los canvas y he quitado el posicionamiento absoluto para que no se posicionen uno encima de otro (para que se vean los 5).

La función per recibe como parámetro el elemento del array b que utiliza para dar un id diferente a cada canvas.

```js
b = [1,2,3,4,5];
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
      
     function per(id) {
      console.log(id);
       var $canvas = $('<canvas id="nodes' + id + '"></canvas>').css({
                'border-radius': '5px',
                'padding': '0',
                'margin': '0',
                'width': '200px',
                'height': '200px',
                //'position': 'absolute',
                'right': '15px',
                'bottom': '15px',
                'background-color': 'blue'
            });
          $('body').append($canvas);
      
     }
    
     $('body').append('<canvas id="minimap"></canvas>');
    
            $('#minimap').css({
                'background': 'rgba(1,1,1,0.7',
                'border-radius': '0px',
                'border': '1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
                'padding': '0',
                'margin': '0',
                'width': '200px',
                'height': '200px',
                'position': 'absolute',
                'right': '15px',
                'bottom': '15px'
            });
        b.forEach(per);
            
      
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: muchas gracias ,pero el problema es que después necesito hacer un document.getElementById , como capturo cada canvas creado si no tienen id?

Comment: Puedes pasarle el valor del elemento de b a la función per y en base a ese valor darle un id diferente a cada canvas.

Comment: eso se me ocurrio pero no tengo mucho conocimiento, edite mi pregunta con lo que intenté

Comment: He editado la respuesta para mostrar cómo hacerlo. El método forEach va a pasar a la función per cada elemento del array como argumento. Puedes utilizar este elemento para dar un id diferente a cada canvas.